# Centripetal Catmull-Rom spline rendered like a dashed line in SFML

Tags: c++, graphics, sfml, spline

I was making a basic paint app in SFML and I wanted to let the user draw smooth curves with the cursor. To achieve this effect, I used the C++ [code for the centripetal Catmull-Rom spline from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_Catmull%E2%80%93Rom_spline#Code_example_in_Unreal_C++)

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but the curve is displayed with a dashed-line effect.

[image: Catmull-Rom Curve]

I would like to know how I can get a smooth continuous curve.
Here's my code.

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

float GetT(float t, float alpha, const sf::Vector2f& p0, const sf::Vector2f& p1)
{
    const sf::Vector2f d = p1 - p0;
    float a = d.x * d.x + d.y * d.y;
    float b = std::pow(a, alpha * 0.5f);
    return (b + t);
}

std::vector<sf::Vector2f> CentripetalCatmullRom(
    const sf::Vector2f& p0,
    const sf::Vector2f& p1,
    const sf::Vector2f& p2,
    const sf::Vector2f& p3
)
{
    const float alpha = 0.5f;
    std::vector<sf::Vector2f> ret;
    float t0 = 0.0f;
    float t1 = GetT(t0, alpha, p0, p1);
    float t2 = GetT(t1, alpha, p1, p2);
    float t3 = GetT(t2, alpha, p2, p3);

    for (float x = 0.f; x < 1.f; x += 0.1f)
    {
        const float t = t1 + x * (t2 - t1);
        sf::Vector2f a1 = p0 * ((t1 - t) / (t1 - t0)) + p1 * ((t - t0) / (t1 - t0));
        sf::Vector2f a2 = p1 * ((t2 - t) / (t2 - t1)) + p2 * ((t - t1) / (t2 - t1));
        sf::Vector2f a3 = p2 * ((t3 - t) / (t3 - t2)) + p3 * ((t - t2) / (t3 - t2));
        sf::Vector2f b1 = a1 * ((t2 - t) / (t2 - t0)) + a2 * ((t - t0) / (t2 - t0));
        sf::Vector2f b2 = a2 * ((t3 - t) / (t3 - t1)) + a3 * ((t - t1) / (t3 - t1));
        sf::Vector2f c = b1 * ((t2 - t) / (t2 - t1)) + b2 * ((t - t1) / (t2 - t1));
        ret.push_back(c);
    }
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1280, 720), "My window");
    std::vector <sf::Vector2f> points;
    sf::Texture texture;
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    texture.create(window.getSize().x, window.getSize().y);

    bool dragging = false;
    window.setFramerateLimit(144);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
            else if ((event.type == sf::Event::MouseMoved) && dragging)
            {
                points.push_back(sf::Vector2f(sf::Mouse::getPosition(window)));
            }
            else if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed)
            {
                dragging = true;
            }
            else if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased)
            {
                dragging = false;
                texture.update(window);
                points.clear(); // saved in texture
            }
        }

        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
        window.draw(sprite);

        sf::VertexArray vertices(sf::LineStrip, 0);

        for (int i = 0; i + 3 < points.size(); i++)
        {
            std::vector<sf::Vector2f> spline_points = CentripetalCatmullRom(points[i],
                points[i + 1],
                points[i + 2],
                points[i + 3]);

            for (auto& v : spline_points)
            {
                vertices.append(sf::Vertex(v, sf::Color::White));
            }
        }

        window.draw(vertices);
        sprite.setTexture(texture);
        window.display();

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the *CentripetalCatmullRom* the 0.1f in the

```
for (float x = 0.f; x < 1.f; x += 0.1f)
```

defines the amount of points you get.

You have two options here:

1. Decrease the step to get more points.
2. Draw spline not by points, but by lines to cover the gaps.